# Reading pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to compere schools in my city based on final exams score, and data is provided in pdf here:
 https://oke.wroc.pl/wp-content/uploads/library/File/pdfy/Powiaty_E8_192/0264.pdf

Unfortunately simple solutions of reading pdf to python did not work. 
I have tried:

1. `PyPDF2` package, but it gave error `PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'39' b'0' [pdf.py:1666]`
2. `textract` package, but it gave error `stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pipe' referenced before assignment`
3. `tabula` package, but it gave error

Got stderr: sty 27, 2020 5:33:46 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2

```
 INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F1 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:46 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F2 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:46 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F3 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:46 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F4 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO: Your current java version is: 1.8.0_131
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO: To get higher rendering speed on old java 1.8 or 9 versions,
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO:   update to the latest 1.8 or 9 version (>= 1.8.0_191 or >= 9.0.4),
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO:   or
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO:   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
    INFO:   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F1 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F2 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F3 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F4 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F1 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F2 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F3 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
    sty 27, 2020 5:33:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
    INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font CIDFont+F4 are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-17-2f598bf9e926>", line 7, in <module>
        df.head()

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'`
```

Comment: I have worked with pdfminer. So far it's better then the ones you mentioned.

Comment: "`PyPDF2` package, but it gave error ..." is not an *error*, it's just a warning. And when properly looping over all pages, you get it for *every* object ... (It's a Bad PDF.) Unfortunately `PyPDF2` cannot handle the nonstandard encoding and parse `ToUnicode`.

Comment: `but it gave error` - no, that is an INFO.

Comment: Yes, you are right. its an info, not error, but still it did not work and did not read a pdf. I guess it is just bad pdf